# Why does IIS show it's own error message for 403 errors instead of relying on my customErrors element?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, http-status-code-403

I'm getting a request like `http://example.com/%2f..%2fwindows%2fsomething.ini` and IIS is displaying "Forbidden URL - HTTP Error 403. The request URL is forbidden."

I think this request is getting blocked at the IIS level.  How can I get IIS to let this error fall through to my application so I can show the error page the rest of my application uses?  404 errors fall through nicely as expected using the customErrors attribute in the web.config:

```
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/content/error.html">
    </customErrors>
```

If I enter a simpler invalid URL like `http://example.com/asdfasdfas/asdfasdf` then my customErrors handler kicks in as desired.

Comment: You might get some hints from https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/jun/01/bypassing-iis-error-messages-in-aspnet The custom errors system from both IIS and ASP.NET can conflict with each other in certain cases, so you need to decide which one to prefer.

Answer (score 0):

403 is iis error. look like your asp.net error is not firing. you could try to add below code in the web.config file:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" errorMode="Custom"> 
<remove statusCode="403"/>
<error statusCode="403" path="/errorpage.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
```

you could also use iis manager to modify the changes:

1)open iis manager, select your site.

2)double click error pages.

[image]

3)set error page as suggested below or as per your requirement.

[image]

[Why is IIS 7 showing me a default 403 page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409942/why-is-iis-7-showing-me-a-default-403-page)

[ASP MVC 5 - 403 customError not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765543/asp-mvc-5-403-customerror-not-working)

Comment: Thanks Jalpa, this didn't seem to work for me though.

Comment: @theycallmemorty if you are using .net mvc site then you could refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565098/asp-net-mvc-5-custom-error-page